# ORA-00979 not a group by expression with case

Tags: java, oracle

Getting `ORA-00979 not a group by expression`
I cannot find the issue.

All select parameters appear in the group by:

```
select case when :contract_number like '001-CR-%' then t.PARTNER_NAME else t.OPPORTUNITY_NAME end merchant_name,
       case when :contract_number like '001-CR-%' then t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_PRT else t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_MER end contract_id, 
       t.target_mid_id as terminal_number,
       t.ACQ_POSTING_DATE as posting_date,
       'Processing Activity' category, 
       case when ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE='Refund' then 'Refund (Credit)' else ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE end as TRX_TYPE_DESC, 
       cu.CURRENCY_ID,
       sum(t.SETTLE_AMOUNT_ORG) as "SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT_ORG)",
       count(*)
from tmp_proc t
join DWH.DIM_TRX_TYPE ty on t.TRX_TYPE_KEY = ty.TRX_TYPE_KEY
join tmp_currency cu on cu.CURRENCY_KEY = t.SETTLE_CURRENCY_KEY


group by case when :contract_number like '001-CR-%' then t.PARTNER_NAME else t.OPPORTUNITY_NAME end,
       case when :contract_number like '001-CR-%' then t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_PRT else t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_MER end, 
       t.target_mid_id,
       t.ACQ_POSTING_DATE,
       'Processing Activity', 
       case when ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE='Refund' then 'Refund (Credit)' else ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE end, 
       cu.CURRENCY_ID
```

Comment: The way I see it, it is OK as far as Oracle (database) is concerned. Are you sure that this is the query that raises the error? I see you tagged the question with Java tag. Could it be that it spoils the query? (I don't speak Java).

Comment: Are those two empty lines, between the `join` and the `group by`, actually part of the query text you are trying to execute?  If so, get rid of them.  If not, edit your question to show the exact query text.

Comment: it is with empty lines, removed them, same error

Comment: where do you run the query? Could it be the empty line is treated as end of query (it might be depends on settings)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query using sub-query as following:

```
SELECT
    MERCHANT_NAME,
    CONTRACT_ID,
    TERMINAL_NUMBER,
    POSTING_DATE,
    CATEGORY,
    TRX_TYPE_DESC,
    CURRENCY_ID,
    SUM(SETTLE_AMOUNT_ORG) AS "SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT_ORG)",
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN :CONTRACT_NUMBER LIKE '001-CR-%' THEN T.PARTNER_NAME
                ELSE T.OPPORTUNITY_NAME
            END MERCHANT_NAME,
            CASE
                WHEN :CONTRACT_NUMBER LIKE '001-CR-%' THEN T.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_PRT
                ELSE T.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_MER
            END CONTRACT_ID,
            T.TARGET_MID_ID      AS TERMINAL_NUMBER,
            T.ACQ_POSTING_DATE   AS POSTING_DATE,
            'Processing Activity' CATEGORY,
            CASE
                WHEN TY.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE = 'Refund' THEN 'Refund (Credit)'
                ELSE TY.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE
            END AS TRX_TYPE_DESC,
            CU.CURRENCY_ID,
            T.SETTLE_AMOUNT_ORG
        FROM
            TMP_PROC T
            JOIN DWH.DIM_TRX_TYPE TY ON T.TRX_TYPE_KEY = TY.TRX_TYPE_KEY
            JOIN TMP_CURRENCY CU ON CU.CURRENCY_KEY = T.SETTLE_CURRENCY_KEY
    )
GROUP BY
    MERCHANT_NAME,
    CONTRACT_ID,
    TERMINAL_NUMBER,
    POSTING_DATE,
    CATEGORY,
    TRX_TYPE_DESC,
    CURRENCY_ID
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way.  Don't put case expressions into the group by clause.

Try re-writing query without case expression at all:

```
select col1,col2,col3,count(*) from tab group by col1,col2,col3;
```

When you have that working then wrap in another sql to do case expressions:

```
select case when :var1 then col1 else col2 end,case when col1 then col2 else null end from (
select col1,col2,col3,count(*) from tab group by col1,col2,col3
);
```

That may work better.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the CASE logic from the GROUP BY by putting the CASE's into a Common Table Expression, then perform the GROUP BY on the CTE:

```
WITH cteData AS(SELECT CASE
                         WHEN :contract_number LIKE '001-CR-%' THEN t.PARTNER_NAME
                         ELSE t.OPPORTUNITY_NAME
                       END AS MERCHANT_NAME,
                       CASE
                         WHEN :contract_number LIKE '001-CR-%' THEN t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_PRT
                         ELSE t.ACQ_CONTRACT_NUM_MER
                       END AS CONTRACT_ID, 
                       t.TARGET_MID_ID AS TERMINAL_NUMBER,
                       t.ACQ_POSTING_DATE AS POSTING_DATE,
                       'Processing Activity' AS CATEGORY, 
                       CASE
                         WHEN ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE='Refund' THEN 'Refund (Credit)'
                         ELSE ty.CREDORAX_TRX_TYPE
                       END AS TRX_TYPE_DESC, 
                       cu.CURRENCY_ID,
                       t.SETTLE_AMOUNT_ORG
                  FROM TMP_PROC t
                  INNER JOIN DWH.DIM_TRX_TYPE ty
                    ON t.TRX_TYPE_KEY = ty.TRX_TYPE_KEY
                  INNER JOIN TMP_CURRENCY cu
                    ON cu.CURRENCY_KEY = t.SETTLE_CURRENCY_KEY)
SELECT MERCHANT_NAME,
       CONTRACT_ID, 
       TERMINAL_NUMBER,
       POSTING_DATE,
       CATEGORY, 
       TRX_TYPE_DESC, 
       CURRENCY_ID,
       SUM(SETTLE_AMOUNT_ORG) AS "SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT_ORG)",
       COUNT(*)
  FROM cteData
  GROUP BY MERCHANT_NAME,
           CONTRACT_ID, 
           TERMINAL_NUMBER,
           POSTING_DATE,
           CATEGORY, 
           TRX_TYPE_DESC, 
           CURRENCY_ID
```

### EDIT

I also suggest getting rid of the uses of `LIKE` here, replacing them with a simple `SUBSTR` call, as in:

```
CASE
  WHEN SUBSTR(:contract_number, 1, 7) ='001-CR-' THEN t.PARTNER_NAME
  ELSE t.OPPORTUNITY_NAME
END AS MERCHANT_NAME
```